# Task.Factory.StartNew Passing return values

Tags: c#, task

i gote the following method and i want to pass the return values of the dosleep method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => dosleep(2000));
    var t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => dosleep(1000));
    Task.WaitAll(t1,t2);
    Console.WriteLine("All Done in {0} milliseconds!"); //t1+t2 here!!
}

public static int dosleep(int Milliseconds)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(Milliseconds);
    Console.WriteLine("Task finished");
    return Milliseconds;
}
```

Comment: will you always have just t1 and t2? or is that dynamic?

Comment: Is the goal simply to add the total ms of all tasks as in @Stilgar's answer or is it to find the total amount of time elapsed during `Task.WaitAll`? I.e., do you expect the result to be ~2000ms or ~3000ms?

Comment: @DavidPeden it's about passing values, the milliseconds are just a example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [Result](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the Task object

```
Console.WriteLine("All Done in {0} milliseconds!", t1.Result + t2.Result);
```